# Названия административных учреждений

Tags: прописная-строчная, названия

Здравствуйте! Региональные министерства (**региональное М(м)инистерство строительства**), управления ведомств (**региональное У(у)правление ФМС**), **Д(д)ума** - в значении облдумы (*т. е. усеченное слово от неполного названия*) - как следует оформлять названия этих учреждений? Также меня интересует оформление названий комиссий, комитетов (**региональная К(к)омиссия по борьбе с коррупцией, региональный К(к)омитет по образованию**). Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

В официальных названиях министерств и главных государственных аппаратов управления с большой буквы пишутся только первое слово и входящие в их состав имена собственные. Это же правило касается и культурных организаций крупного масштаба: Министерство иностранных дел.
При неофициальном употреблении верно написание со строчной буквы. Напр.: в министерстве сообщили...

> При отсутствии полного названия слова "департамент", "управление", "комиссия" пишутся со строчной буквы.
>
> См.:[Культура устной и письменной речи делового человека: Справочник. Практикум. - 4-е изд.-М.:Флинта:Наука,2000.
> Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В.,Кабанова Н.П. Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию.
> Издание четвертое, исправленное.- М.: "ЧеРо", 2001](http://gramma.ru/SPR/?id=5.12)

Comment: Я вижу некоторое противоречие, ведь согласно правилу усеченное название пишется с большой, например Областной драмтеатр от, скажем, Воронежский областной драматический театр. Или это не относится к названиям административных учреждений?

Comment: Никаких противоречий. В усеченном названии с прописной буквы пишется начальное слово (помимо первого слова и собственных имен) той части, которая сама по себе употребляется в функции того же названия, например: Государственный Исторический музей (***ср.: Исторический музей***), Государственная Публичная библиотека имени М.Е. Салтыкова-Щедрина (ср.: ***Публичная библиотека имени М.Е. Салтыкова-Щедрина)***, Государственная ***Третьяковская галерея*** (ср.: ***Третьяковская галерея***),

Comment: Как видите, правило в основном касается зрелищных предприятий и учреждений культуры. В примере, который вы приводите, ***областной театр*** не может писаться с прописной буквы, т.к. он не употребляется в качестве отдельного названия. Областной драмтеатр скорее сокращение от ***Областной драматический театр***

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Государственная Публичная библиотека имени М. Е. Салтыкова-Щедрина — разве слово "публичная" пишется с заглавной? Или вы это повысили, чтобы подчеркнуть слово-пример?

Comment: Да, с прописной.  Т. к. "Публичная библиотека'' сама по себе употребляется в качестве названия.